# Copy file from the user selected path and place it in project folder as backup

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, file-rename, file-copying

I have a user form to browse an excel file & a text file into 2 different textboxs (Selectionfile say ABC.xlsx & relationshipfile say GHJ.txt resp.) from local folders. On clicking the **proceed button**, the selected file must be copied from the path to the project location used by the program with same filenames with date(ABC_27092016.xlsx & GHJ_27092016.txt resp. as backup files) and in case if the file already exists with the same filename (if user selects the same filename in the user form) then the message should show "if to continue with the existing file in project folder? or replace it with the new file selected". If user selects replace then it should replace with the new file & date. If user selects not to replace it should not copy but proceed to next step.

[image: Uesr from with fields and Proceed button]

This is the code below which just copies but doe not do the process above to check if file exist already or 

'back up selected files to project folder & rename with date

```
Private Sub Proceed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Proceed.Click
    Dim selectionpath As String = selectionfilepath  'selectionpath is from the textbox1 in userform 
    Dim relationpath As String = relationshipfilepath  'relationpath is from the textbox2 in userform 
    Dim Timestamp As Date = Now   
    Dim destination1 As String = "C:\Users\UserA\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NetSoftware\Files\Example_selectionfile_" & Format(Timestamp, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"  
    Dim destination2 As String = "C:\Users\UserA\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NetSoftware\Files\Example_relationfile_" & Format(Timestamp, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt" 

    If (SelectionFIleName.Text = "" Or RelationshipFileName.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the file")
    Else
        FileCopy(selectionpath, destination1) 'copying the excel file to project location 
        FileCopy(relationpath, destination2)  'copying text file to project location 
        Rename(destination1, selectionpath)   'renaming the excel file since it stores as Example_selectionfile instead of the exact name of the user slected filename and also missing the date
        Rename(destination2, relationpath)    'renaming the excel file since it stores as Example_relationfile instead of the exact name of the user slected filename and also missing the date
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are selectionfilepath and relationshipfilepath variables that store the values of textbox1 and textbox2 respectivly or the actual names of the text box? Try setting selectionpath to selectionfilepath.Text and relationpath to relationshipfilepath.text if they are the actual names of the text box. I cannot see that you assign the textbox1.Text or textbox2.Text anyway so it is a bit hard to answer.

Comment: I have selectionfilepath = OpenSelectionFileDialog1.FileName and relationshipfilepath = OpenRelationshipFileDialog1.FileName in 2 sub classes to browse the files.

Comment: This is the sub code

    Private Sub SelectionButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectionButton.Click
        OpenSelectionFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
        If OpenSelectionFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            SelectionFIleName.Text = OpenSelectionFileDialog1.FileName
            selectionfilepath = OpenSelectionFileDialog1.FileName
            selectionfile = IO.Path.GetFileName(selectionfilepath)
        End If
    End Sub